# Transform Dot Notation to JSON - javascript

Tags: javascript, json, npm

How to convert dot notation to JSON? Below sample dot that getting from BE & I need to convert it to JSON, example -

```
digraph {
"Stream|4a150498-7f00-430b-861d-88d3ea381f66" [name=Stream,inputs=" 
['']",Properties="{}",Position="[50,50]"]
"From|6624da0b-7b2d-4381-a2c3-4f00c9cf9e0b" [name=From,inputs=" 
['']",Properties="{'Database':['cloudDB'],'Measurement': 
['sensorData'],'RetentionPolicy':['oneUnit']}",Position="[317,49]"]
}
```

Is there a method or npm library in Javascript that will help me to achieve the above. Guys pls share ..

Comment: Dot notation? There are no dots in your question.

Comment: what does "dot notation" mean?

Comment: Its not related to dot notation used in javascript. I am talking about <filename>.dot file type, which is mainly used  for analysis purpose with jsplumb library